# Как обрезать значение переменной по знакам?

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть переменная, которая равна некому числу (или даже слову).

```
$a = 1234567890;
```

Хочу другой переменной дать то же значение, но с определенного до определенного знака от ее начала. К примеру

```
$b = " с_третьего_по_седьмой_знак($a) "
```

т.е. что бы получилось, что

```
$b = 34567
```

Подскажите команду. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$from = 3;
$to = 7;
$num = $to - $from; // 
$b = substr($a, $from); // 3..strlen($a)
$b = substr($a, $from, $num); // 3..7
$b = substr($a, -5, 2); // (strlen($a)-5)..(strlen($a)-3)
```